# Laravel controller not displaying image from s3 bucket

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I want to display an image from my amazon s3 bucket directly in the users browser from my controller. For this purpose I'm using [Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem). From the documentation it seems like my code should work but in my browser it displays nothing. It also doesn't show any errors, only a black screen in the browser.

Here is my controller `S3ImageController.php`

```
class S3ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function imageUrl($make, $model, $year) {

        $stock = DB::table('stock_car_images')
            ->where(compact('make', 'model', 'year'))
            ->first();

        if (!empty($stock) && Storage::disk('s3')->url($stock->image)) {
            return response(Storage::disk('s3')->get($stock->image))->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        } else {
            return 'No Image';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `->where(compact('make', 'model', 'year'))` - Does not seem right at all. AFAIK the parameter ordering is: `(column, operator = null, value)`. If operator is omitted then it defaults to `=`.

Comment: the parameters work exactly as it should, but it doesn't work the File Storage part

Comment: @Script47 The `where()` function on the query builder can take an array of conditions, so the posted code will work.